Building Angular 18 Elements in a library and exporting them to be used in plain html
I created an Angular workspace with 2 projects:

Library - has components which are intended to be used as web elements
Demo app - I'll be using this app to develop the components in my library (this is not going to be used.. only for development purposes)

I've been struggling with this for days now, I'll summarize my questions as below:

What is the best method to build and register my components to be used in plain html file? is creating the library a good idea? I can't find a way for it to register the web elements on its own using the library.
when building the library, I end up with output files which are .mjs files which have imports to some libraries from the node_modules folder. how can I include the code of those imports in my files so that all I have to do is to just use the web elements directives alone? I don't want to reference some node_modues when using the elements

